# Instaling composer for laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, composer-php

I have a problem with instaling composer for laravel framework:

I have this error:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I try everything I find on net - change php.ini, instal via CMD but nothing work...

I really dont understand what can be a problem here. Please help.

Here is a image of what I try:

[image]

Comment: Did you edited the php.ini located where your php.exe is?

Comment: `php -i | grep Configuration` will tell you the location of the loaded configuration file used by your command line PHP

Comment: I will try to edit php.ini where php.exe is now

Comment: @jrenk THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I SPEND ALL DAY TO see where is the error

Comment: Now I cant install laravel: http://i.imgur.com/hCcjKkk.png - say instalation failed

Comment: What version of PHP are you actually running from your command line? Do `php -v` to check

Comment: Definetely looks like wrong PHP version...

Comment: yes, php verion was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong PHP Version.

Personally, I wouldn't bother to fix it. Use [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) to create a virtual ubuntu instance. Everything will be up and running in minutes